# How do I add Google Adsense every x posts?

Tags: tumblr, ads

I found this example http://wearevanity.co where the new ads are loaded in every page.

In addition to the maximum number of posts allowed by `Tumblr`. The ads are automatically adjusted to the layout of the page, which makes them add to the look of the blog.

Does anyone know how to achieve this? If so, would you please explain it to us, step by step?

Comment: A quick Google reveals: http://www.agentwp.com/how-to-insert-adsense-code-after-first-second-or-nth-post-in-wordpress

Comment: @Len_D That's WordPress, not Tumblr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `{block:Post6}` and `{block:Post12}` to show content on the 6th and 12th posts. [Documentation here](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#posts)

Example usage:

```
{block:Posts}
    {block:Photo}Your content blocks here{/block:Photo}
    {block:Video}Your content blocks here{/block:Video}

    {block:Post6} Your ad code here{/block:Post6}
    {block:Post12}Your ad code here{/block:Post12}
{/block:Posts}
```

Comment: Thanks. It actually works but not quite. I'd like to have posts 6 and post 12 being rendered individually, not within an existing post, as you can see here: http://wearevanity.co ; Any guesses? Would be much appreciated.

Comment: That code does exactly what's on that site: it adds the ad code after every 6th and 12th posts on _lists_ pages. I don't know what you mean by _"I'd like to have posts 6 and post 12 being rendered individually, not within an existing post"_

Comment: Hey, I appreciate your reply. Thanks for taking the time. If you look closely, the ads at wearevanity.co have their own photo-border. It's almost as if they were loaded as 'fake' photo-posts. The code you gave me makes the ads appear under the photo-posts, sharing the same photo-borders as those same posts. And that doesn't add to the look of the site. I even tried customising ads, and tried different dimensions, but it doesn't work, and the ads are often displayed in half. They must be loaded individually. Any other guesses you might have?

Comment: Yes, that's a separate issue. It's on you to apply a custom style to make it appear as if they are fake photo posts.

Answer (score 1):

Add this

```
{block:Post6} Your ad code here{/block:Post6}
{block:Post12}Your ad code here{/block:Post12}
```

above `{/block:Posts}` to add ads.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution and the ads look great, and have their own photo-border, adding to the look of the blog. I used bfred's method and placed the ad code right before

```
{/block:Posts}
```

However, even though the ads were being loaded after posts 6 and 12, they were inside those posts, sharing the same photo-border, and that didn't add up to the look of the whole theme. So I looked for the line of code that was causing the photos to be organised and have their own space on the grid. In my case this was the line:

```
<article id="{PostID}" class="entry{block:HasTags}
{block:Tags} tag-{Tag}{/block:Tags}
{/block:HasTags}{block:Photo} photo-border{/block:Photo}">
```

Once I found it, after trying different placements, I finally placed this line inside

```
{block:Post6} {/block:Post6}
```

I also had to change the size of the ads so that the width could match the width of the photo-posts on my blog. So the final code looks like this:

```
{block:Post6}

<article id="{PostID}" class="entry{block:HasTags}
{block:Tags} tag-{Tag}{/block:Tags}    
{/block:HasTags}{block:Photo} photo-border{/block:Photo}">

<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- page -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
 style="display:inline-block;width:264px;height:250px"
 data-ad-client="ca-pub-7147439154267017"
 data-ad-slot="1006289886"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>

</article>

{/block:Post6}


{block:Post12}

<article id="{PostID}" class="entry{block:HasTags}
{block:Tags} tag-{Tag}{/block:Tags}     
{/block:HasTags}{block:Photo} photo-border{/block:Photo}">

<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- page -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
 style="display:inline-block;width:264px;height:250px"
 data-ad-client="ca-pub-7147439154267017"
 data-ad-slot="1006289886"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>


</article>

{/block:Post12}
```