# TUMBLR: How can hide a div when the page number is higher than 1?

Tags: javascript, html, tumblr

Here's what I have so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

if ($("{CurrentPage}").length > 1) {
  $("#comslider_in_point_234708").style.display="none";

}

</script>
```

Here are tumblr's variables (I'm not sure which one to use, as none seem to work):

- `{block:Pagination}{/block:Pagination}`
  Rendered if there is a "previous" or "next" page.
- `{block:PreviousPage}{/block:PreviousPage}`
  Rendered if there is a "previous" page (newer posts) to navigate to.
- `{block:NextPage}{/block:NextPage}`
  Rendered if there is a "next" page (older posts) to navigate to.
- `{PreviousPage}`
  URL for the "previous" page (newer posts).
- `{NextPage}`
  URL for the "next" page (older posts).
- `{CurrentPage}`
  Current page number.
- `{TotalPages}`
  Total page count.

Comment: Have you tried using `if ({CurrentPage} > 1) {...}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
if ({CurrentPage} > 1) {
  document.getElementById("comslider_in_point_234708").style.display="none";

}
</script>
```

No need to use `length` in the function

Comment: YES! Thanks you so much! I've been searching for a solution for hours! Thank you!

Comment: Chose my answer than remved it as the accepted answer? -1

Comment: sorry, I'm new to this and I thought I could choose more than 1 as correct answers. You were the first to answer so you should be rightfully rewarded.

Answer (score 3):

**You already got an answer, but I think we can do better than just give you the code.**

One problem with your JavaScript was that you were trying to get a HTML element with the jQuery selector, and the Tumblr variable isn't a HTML element, it's just a variable. Then we've removed the jQuery element selector from your code, like this:

```
if ({CurrentPage}.length > 1) {
  document.getElementById("comslider_in_point_234708").style.display="none";
}
```

But your code will still have other problem, because this way you are checking if the variable `length` property is greater to **1**, not the variable actual value, so if the variable is equal to **2** or **9** for example, the comparison will return `false` and cause the `if` to fail.

This occurs because the `length` property return the number of characters in the variable, not it's value *(so `10.length` returns **2** and `1000.length` returns **4**)*. To solve this problem, we've also removed it, leaving you code like this:

```
if ({CurrentPage} > 1) {
  document.getElementById("comslider_in_point_234708").style.display="none";
}
```

Then when the code is executed in the 11th page, the `{CurrentPage}` variable will contain the number **11** and the code will run as:

```
if (11 > 1) { // returns true
  document.getElementById("comslider_in_point_234708").style.display="none";
}
```

Also, if you are using jQuery, you can improve your code by replacing the line inside the `if` with this:

```
$("#comslider_in_point_234708").hide();
```

...That uses the jQuery selector that you've used in the wrong place before, and jQuery's `hide()` method, that is equivalent to `display:none`.

---

**So, finally, here's the result:**

```
if ({CurrentPage} > 1) {
  $("#comslider_in_point_234708").hide();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Post Offsets**

Its possible to do this with Tumblrs own theme operators, rather than javascript. The block, `{block:Post[1-15]}`, allow you to specify a post offset. From the OPs example, I would use `Post2`.

```
<style>

  <!-- Hide comslider if there is a second post on the page -->
  {block:Post2}
  #comslider_in_point_234708 {
    display: none;
  }
  {/block:Post2}

</style>
```

**Reference**

[Posts Basic Variables](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#posts)

Comment: Thanks mikedidthis! Btw, I've got a question for everyone. Could you possibly have a guess at how to show ads on my blog exactly like the ones on this site: http://wearevanity.co ? If you look closely they act almost as "ghost posts", having their own photo-border, and automatically adjusting themselves to the grid.

Comment: @user3624466 I would post is as a new question. tl;dr, use the above block or inject them into the document flow with javascript.

Comment: I already posted it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24222941/how-do-i-add-google-adsense-every-x-posts 
The method described in there is a solution, but not quite. I still think there's a way of achieving the exact same result. I tried adding custom css, but just can't figure out how to make the ads load as new photo-posts, or "ghost posts".

Comment: This is a good answer. I don't understand how if ({CurrentPage}) > 1 would work as that is part of the mustache template and surely only standard HTML will be rendered at run time so the js would fail?

Comment: @lharby Thanks. `{CurrentPage}` would be rendered as a number in the HTML, so the statement would work. I believe the theme operators are custom, though they do look like handlebars / mustache / smarty etc.

Comment: @user3624466 That solution is how I have done it in the past.